# How can I create a count down number for setTimeout in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I am trying to create count down number for undo button.

For example: when the User hits the invite button to invite another user into the team and the invitation will count down from 10 to 0 and then send the invite if not click to undo button.

Here is my following code:

```
const InviteCard = (props) => {
  const {
    user,
    tab,
    teamId,
    privateTeamId,
    onSubmiteInvitee,
    isInvitationAvailable,
    searchQuery,
    invite,
  } = props;

  async function inviteToTeam(e) {
    if (!user.verifiedDT) {
      notify("User has not verified their identity, can not invite.");
    } else {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/invites/invite", {
        userToInvite: user.public_user_id,
        teamId: teamId,
      });
      if (res.data.inviteWasCreated === false) {
        notify("User has already been invited.");
      } else if (res.data.error !== undefined) {
        notify(res.data.error);
      } else if (res.data.msg) {
        if (res.data.msg === "max members") {
          toggleRequestModal();
          setLimitType("team members");
        }
        if (res.data.msg === "max invites") {
          toggleRequestModal();
          setLimitType("invites");
        }
      } else {
        notify("Invite sent.");
        setWhatToReload("invite data");
        onSubmiteInvitee(e);
      }
    }
  }

 const [sent, setSent] = useState(false);
  const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState();
  const handleSubmitInvite = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // call "inviteToTeam" function after 10s
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      inviteToTeam(e);
    }, 10 * 1000);

    setSent(!sent);
    // save the timer id in the state
    setTimeoutId(id);
  };

  const onUndoClick = (timeoutId) => {
    // get the timeout id from the state
    // and cancel the timeout
    setSent(false);
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  };

        {!sent &&
          !isInvitationAvailable(privateTeamId, user.InvitesApplications) && (
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmitInvite}>
                <button type="submit" className="invitees-invite-button">
                  Invite
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          )}
        {sent && <button onClick={onUndoClick}>Undo</button>}
```

How can I achieve this feature? Do I need to use lodash??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const [count, setCount] = useState(10);

 const handleSubmitInvite = () => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((currentCount) => --currentCount);
    }, 1000);
    //execute your function
    if (count === 0) {your fuction};

    // cleanup
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
 }

 const onUndoClick = () => {
   setSent(false);
 };
```

Comment: `your function` is it `inviteToTeam()`?

Comment: any function you want to trigger after the count

Comment: in the `onUndoClick` line `clearTimeout(interval)` how to send interval into that button

Comment: Im getting interval is undefined

Comment: meanwhile, you can access 'count' in the state.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not quite get what you mean by access count in the state. You mean like `clearTimeout(count);`?

Comment: check updated code for the handleSubmitInvite. And write a separate function for onUndoClick.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in function `onUndoClick`. You have a state with name `timeoutId`, but the `onUndoClick` function accepts a parameter with the same name, so it uses value of the parameter, and you never use actual state value and never cancel the timeout. Try with:

```js
// parameter removed
const onUndoClick = () => {
    // get the timeout id from the state
    // and cancel the timeout
    setSent(false);
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  };
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I create a count down 10 to 0 if the invite button click?

Comment: @nathan you want to wait for 10 seconds before sending an invite, am i correct?

Comment: @nathan I think this solution will do it.

Comment: I mean yea but how can I show to user the number count down

Comment: like 10 9 ... 0 in the button. I thought we need to use `setInterval`